# PHP: Email Parsing - Multiple Recipients

Tags: php, regex, parsing, email

I am piping email that get's sent to my server to a PHP script. The script parses the email so I can assign variables.

My problem is once in awhile somebody will include my email address to an email that's getting sent to multiple recipients and my script will only get the first one. I need it to find my email address then assign it to a variable.

Here is what the email array looks like: http://pastebin.com/0gdQsBYd

Using the example above I would need to get the 4th recipient: my_user_email@mydomain.com

Here is the code I am using to get the "To -> name" and "To -> address"

```
# Get the name and email of the recipient
$toName = $results['To'][0]['name'];
$toEmail = $results['To'][0]['address'];
```

I assume I need to do a `foreach($results['To'] as $to)` then a `preg_match` but I am not good with regular expressions to find the email I want.

Some help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you need a regex if you're just trying to match against a known string.  Why not just use [strcasecmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php)?

Comment: `$results['To'][0]['name'];` does not exist in your script ..

Comment: @MihaiIorga Not in that email it doesn't. Further down in the script I deal with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of usin preg_match inside foreach loop you can use strstr like below

Supposing you are looking for my_user_email@mydomain.com use following code

```
foreach($results['To'] as $to)
{

// gets value occuring before the @, if you change the 3 rd parameter to false returns domain name

$user = strstr($to, '@', true) ;
if($user == 'my_user_email')
{
//your action code goes here
}

}
```

**example:**

```
<?php
$email  = 'name@example.com';
$domain = strstr($email, '@');
echo $domain; // prints @example.com

$user = strstr($email, '@', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0
echo $user; // prints name
?>
```

Comment: Hm, I could see how this would almost work for me, but I actually need to find the @domain.com since my script actually retrieves emails from multiple accounts.

Comment: for that you can simply turn the true flag to false  
$user = strstr($email, '@', false) or dont use the third parameter 
$user = strstr($email, '@') this will five you the domain name of your email

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not need to use a regexp at all. Instead you can use a PHP for statement that loops through your array of To addresses.

```
$count = count($root['To']);
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    //Do something with your To array here using $root['To'][$i]['address']

}
```

Comment: I am not sending email, I am retrieving it.

Comment: then I do not understand what you are trying to do with your script. With the code provided in your link, i assumed u were trying to mass email.
Anyhow, you can still use the following for statement to seperate each recipient in the email and do what you will with them.